TS directive but changing the input param based on boolean
I need to have an input variable be determined by a second boolean variable as directive to be used later on.
type TypeWithAge = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type TypeWithoutAge = MakeOptional<TypeWithAge, "age">;

type TypeWithAgeConditional<withName> = withName extends true ? TypeWithoutAge : TypeWithAge;

Now I need to have the function change the input param based on withName.
async function upsertFunction<withName extends boolean>(
   upsertItem: TypeWithAgeConditional<withName>, 
   includeName: withName
): boolean {
  
  if (includeName){
    upsertItem = { ...upsertItem, name: 'someValue' }
  }

  await writeItemToDb(upsertItem) // TS error since input of writeItemToDb expects TypeWithAge and cannot be changed in my case
  
  return true
}

The only workaround I have thus far is using
await writeItemToDb(upsertItem as TypeWithAge)

Logically it makes sense since the upsertItem will always correctly be of type TypeWithAge but using as xxx feels like a hardcoded pitfall waiting to happen.
How do I get upsertItem to also be of type TypeWithAgeConditional and get writeItemToDb to understand it will always be of correct type TypeWithAge?

There are other questions that use this to determine the output of a function but I have solved that in my code already and still can't get this to work.

Side note: you should define TypeWithAge from TypeWithoutAge because the former is stricter than the latter. "... and get writeItemToDb to understand it will always be of correct type TypeWithAge": how can it always be of TypeWithAge, if it depends on a boolean that can be false?

• Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] without references to private/third-party things like MakeOptional and writeItemToDb.  You should either define/declare those for us or replace them with native TS. Also, please clear up errors unrelated to the question, like illegally returning boolean for an async function. And which thing is optional/added: name or age?  • I've never seen the term "directive" used in the way you're using it. The only meaning for "directive" in TypeScript is a triple-slash directive. Could you [edit] to rephrase/explain that term?

(see prev comment) If I fix all the problems I can find with your code, including settling on age instead of name, I get this version. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer after you [edit] to make the code in the question a [mre]. If not, what am I missing?
